# Can anyone explain part of this opencv code to me?

Tags: c++, opencv

[The original code is here](https://github.com/simena86/handDetectionCV/tree/master/VS2013%20Version)

It's an opencv program used to track hand gestures I'm trying to figure out why the creator of this code needed the c_lower and c_upper arrays

It's too much code to post, I'm mainly wondering if there's someone on here who has used this code before who understands in better than me.

I wondering why he did this:

```
void produceBinaries(MyImage *m) {
    Scalar lowerBound;
    Scalar upperBound;
    for (int i = 0; i<NSAMPLES; i++) {
        normalizeColors(m);
        lowerBound = Scalar(avgColor[i][0] - c_lower[i][0], avgColor[i][1] - c_lower[i][1], avgColor[i][2] - c_lower[i][2]);
        upperBound = Scalar(avgColor[i][0] + c_upper[i][0], avgColor[i][1] + c_upper[i][1], avgColor[i][2] + c_upper[i][2]);
        m->bwList.push_back(Mat(m->srcLR.rows, m->srcLR.cols, CV_8U));
        inRange(m->srcLR, lowerBound, upperBound, m->bwList[i]);
    }
    m->bwList[0].copyTo(m->bw);
    for (int i = 1; i<NSAMPLES; i++) {
        m->bw += m->bwList[i];
    }
    medianBlur(m->bw, m->bw, 7);
}
```

Instead of this

```
void produceBinaries(MyImage *m) {
    Scalar lowerBound;
    Scalar upperBound;
    for (int i = 0; i<NSAMPLES; i++) {
        normalizeColors(m);
        lowerBound = Scalar(avgColor[i][0] - 20, avgColor[i][1] - 20, avgColor[i][2] - 20);
        upperBound = Scalar(avgColor[i][0] + 20, avgColor[i][1] + 20, avgColor[i][2] + 20);
        m->bwList.push_back(Mat(m->srcLR.rows, m->srcLR.cols, CV_8U));
        inRange(m->srcLR, lowerBound, upperBound, m->bwList[i]);
    }
    m->bwList[0].copyTo(m->bw);
    for (int i = 1; i<NSAMPLES; i++) {
        m->bw += m->bwList[i];
    }
    medianBlur(m->bw, m->bw, 7);
}
```

[This code can be found here](https://github.com/simena86/handDetectionCV/blob/master/VS2013%20Version/HandDetection/main.cpp)

Why would he need separate values of c_lower and c_upper for hue, saturation, and value? Why not pick an arbitrary number like 20?

If anyone could be of any help that would be great, the guy hasn't posted anything about this code in years so I don't expect him to reply to me.

Comment: Maybe because he didn't want to have magic numbers in his code?

Comment: @MikeMB then where do his numbers come from?

Comment: As I'm not familiar with this code and you don't even link to the file, where that code comes from I don't know, but your IDE should tell you. Maybe they are the result of a calibration process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because these bounds are controlled by user in GUI and not hardcoded in the code. They are set to initial values in `initTrackbars` to be controlled later using trackbars (a kind of sliders).